# XSLT, RUBY, how to output the next element name from root?

Tags: ruby, xml, csv, xslt, nokogiri

I am working on a ruby script that involves with XSLT to convert XML to CSV. One of my code's logic is to grab the parent node element after root dynamically so it can treat it as row of records in the CSV file. I was able to get what I want by using Oxygen to convert the XML but I am running in this error by using Nokogiri:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.3/lib/nokogiri/xslt.rb:32:in `parse_stylesheet_doc': compilation error: file selectXMLelement.xsl line 5 element stylesheet (RuntimeError)
>   xsl:version: only 1.1 features are supported
>   compilation error: file selectXMLelement.xsl line 8 element value-of
>   xsl:value-of : could not compile select expression 'concat(':',/data:root/*/local-name())'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.3/lib/nokogiri/xslt.rb:32:in`parse'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.3/lib/nokogiri/xslt.rb:13:in `XSLT'
>       from EXTC-v1.rb:37:in`api_component'
>       from EXTC-v1.rb:43:in `block in <main>'
>       from EXTC-v1.rb:43:in`each'
>       from EXTC-v1.rb:43:in `'

I would like to know if there is a way to use Nokogiri to get what I want instead of the XSLT, and how to feed into my Ruby script logic.

I have tried to use this XSLT:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:data="urn:com.sample/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="data"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(':',/data:root/*[1]/local-name())"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

example XML, and I am successfully to output what I want from the XSLT ":Data_Request" by using Oxygen

```
<data:root>
    <data:Data_Request>
        <data:name>John Doe</data:name>
        <data:phone>123456776</data:phone>
    </data:Data_Request>
</data:root>
```

My Ruby script:

```
def xslt_transform(filename)
  #dir = File.join(Dir.pwd,'/input/')
  xml_str = File.read(filename)
  doc = Nokogiri::XML xml_str
  template = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.open('Remove-CDATA.xsl'))
  transformed_doc = template.transform(doc)

  File.write(filename, transformed_doc)
end

Dir.glob('*.xml').each {|filename| xslt_transform(filename)}
#this is where iam trying to use the XSLT
def api_component(filename)
  xml_str = File.read(filename)
  doc = Nokogiri::XML xml_str
  template = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.open('selectXMLelement.xsl'))
  transformed_doc = template.transform(doc)

  puts filename
end

api_name = Dir.glob('*xml').each {|filename| api_component(filename)}

puts api_name


def xml_to_csv(filename)
  dir = File.join(Dir.pwd,'/input/')
  xml_str = File.read(filename)
  doc     = Nokogiri::XML xml_str
  csv_filename = filename.gsub('.xml','.csv')
  record  = {} # hashes
  keys    = Set.new
  records = [] # array
  csv     = ""

# Returns a new hash created by traversing the hash and its subhashes, 
# executing the given block on the key and value. The block should return a 2-element array of the form [key, value].
  doc.traverse do |node| 
    value = node.text.gsub(/\n +/, '')
      if node.name != "text" # skip these nodes: if class isnt text then skip
        if value.length > 0 # skip empty nodes
          key = node.name.gsub(/wd:/,'').to_sym
          #api_component = doc.xpath('/*/*[1]')
          # if a new and not empty record, add to our records collection
          if key == :Data_Request && !record.empty? #for regular XML parsng, use the request data. For example :Location_Data
            records << record
            record = {}
          elsif key[/^root$|^document$/]
            # neglect these keys
          else
            key = node.name.gsub(/data:/,'').to_sym
            # in case our value is html instead of text
            record[key] = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(value).text
            # add to our key set only if not already in the set
            keys << key
          end
        end
      end
    end



# build our csv
  dir = File.join(Dir.pwd,'/output/')
  File.open('../output/'+csv_filename, 'wb') do |file|
    file.puts %Q{"#{keys.to_a.join('","')}"}
    records.each do |record|
      keys.each do |key|
        file.write %Q{"#{record[key]}",}
      end
      file.write "\n"
    end
    print ''
    print filename+ " is ready!\n"
    print ''
  end
end

Dir.glob('*.xml').each { |filename| xml_to_csv(filename) }
```

As you can see, right now I have it hard coded the node element: `if key == :Data_Request && !record.empty?`

Is there a way to do so with Nokogiri? and it can dynamically detect all the XML files in the read path? If not, how can I achieve it with XSLT embeded in my script? 
Side question! Is there a way to make all the data format as Text format with my script too so it can keep the leading zeros? :)

Comment: It looks like nokigiri only supports XSLT 1.0 (Well, 1.1, but that never got out of draft specification, I believe), in which case the syntax `/data:root/*/local-name()` could be invalid. Does doing `<xsl:value-of select="concat(':', local-name(/data:root/*))"/>
` work?

Comment: yes, i got the output to work with nokogiri, thanks! but now the output has: <?xml version="1.0"?>
:Data_Request               how to i remove the <?xml version="1.0"?> from the output? and what do I need to do to apply that output to my ruby script at line: if key ==:Data_Request && !record.empty?

Comment: It looks like there is a [Nokogiri::XML::Searchable#search](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#search-instance_method) method that directly takes an XPath expression; is that what you're looking for?  Or perhaps [Nokogiri::XML::Node#parent](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#parent-instance_method)?

Comment: I tried to use `<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>` or `<xsl:output method="text" />` not working for nokogiri :(

Comment: You're asking three different questions. Don't do that because you just made your question off-topic for being too broad. Instead as one, maybe two questions if they're very closely related. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Comment: XML to CSV is generally pretty easy and doesn't involve an XSLT. Using `traverse` is not the efficient way to use Nokogiri, instead you probably want to define a number of lookups using `css` or `xpath` searches to find specific nodes then extract the specific text, creating an array or hash that you then use to create a row of data in the CSV file.

Comment: Tin Man, thanks alot for your help and tip so far. I tried `def first_element(filename)

  xml_files = File.read(filename)
  doc = Nokogiri::XML xml_files

  doc.traverse do |node|

    puts node.xpath("concat(':', local-name(/data:root/*[1]))")
  end
end


Dir.glob('*xml').each {|filename| first_element(filename)}` but the first element after root came out way too many times, and also showing the whole xml in display. How do I shorten it to just :Data_Request? thanks